# Javascript document.write inside script

Tags: javascript, html, function

I just got into the Javascript basics today in school and there's a problem that I'm having trouble with. 
 
The exercise is to make a html page with a textbox(where I must put a number x) and a button, and when I click the button, the page should form a triangle with asterisks from 1 to the x using the 'document.write' function.

I can do this fine, but the problem is that I need to be able to use this function repetitively, like if I change the number in the textbox and click the button again, a new triangle should be created, and the previous contents must be saved as well.

 
I must only use document.write to achieve this, but using document.write deletes all the previous contents, so in the newly created page the script in the 'head' doesn't exist.

 
Anyone can suggest me anything? 
 
[Here's my code.](http://pastebin.com/TsAR7Pqv)

Comment: use window.open to show output in new window

Answer (score 1):

Get the HTML of body element and append the new pattern to this HTML and write it to document.

```
var bodyHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
var newHtml = "";
//create new pattern and save in newHtml variable

Document.write(bodyHtml + < br /> + newHtml);
```

Comment: Good answer in that it could work in this situation, but it doesn't explain why. Clearly, this is a student who is learning the language and some explanation would go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)), when called from a context like a script tag in the head of the document, will call `document.open` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.open)) beforehand, which will reinitialize the document, overwriting any previous content. However, subsequent calls to `document.write` *will not* overwrite previously-written content if you haven't called `document.open` or `document.close` explicitly.

You can save what you have previously written to the document in a variable and you can call `document.open` beforehand. Something like the following:

```
    var ShowOnPage = '<input type="text" id="text1" />' + '<input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="CreateTriangle()" /> <br/>';
    function CreateTriangle() {
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value);
        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                ShowOnPage += "*";
            }
            ShowOnPage += "<br/>"
        }
        document.open();
        document.write(ShowOnPage);
        document.close();
    }
```

Note that `ShowOnPage` is created *outside* of the function to create a triangle and is initialized with the value of the inputs that you want to keep around between clicks. Also note the use of `document.open` and `document.close` around the `document.write` calls.

---

As a side note, why is `document.write` required here? This is *not* the way that you would implement something like this, and teaching the use of something like `document.write` that is almost never used in a real situation is doing nothing to increase knowledge of web development.

You can get the same concepts across by introducing `innerHTML` and `getElementById` and adjusting the content of  a certain element, [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/HHmCS/).

Comment: I have to agree with you on the ``document.write`` issue. But sadly, that's probably how their teacher learned it from some javascript book that was written years ago. They should learn about what makes javascript special, and that's certainly not ``document.write``.

Comment: When `document.write` is used `document.open` may be called _implicit_ for the case where the `document` is closed (e.g. was fully loaded to DOM). So if `document.write` is called when the dom is not ready then it will be inserted at the place where the current script execution was initiated or may be appended even if it is called with a `setTimeout( ... )`, if e.g. document is transferred with chunk encoding and there are still chunks pending.

Comment: that is the big problem, she specifically told us not to use innerHTML, but to find a way to do it using document.write